# How Yarn Checksum works?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I was reading about the Yarn and its difference to NPM from the link - https://medium.com/@nikjohn/facebooks-yarn-vs-npm-is-yarn-really-better-1890b3ea6515

but I didn't understand the following points about yarn -

- Yarn uses checksums to verify the integrity of every installed package before executing code.
  (so the NPM doesn't check like this?)
- Concise lockfile format, and a deterministic algorithm for installs. This means that Yarn is able to guarantee that an install that worked on one system will work exactly the same way on any other system. Isn’t that what you always wanted?
- Yarn installed the dependencies using parallel approach, That's why it is faster package download manager than NPM. (but how?)

Can someone please clarify the above points?